# What exactly does the mock function do?

Tags: java, sockets, mocking

I found this code in a sample project and I've never seen anything like it before.

```
private final SocketFactory mockedSockFactory = mock(SocketFactory.class)
```

What exactly does it mean? What does `mock` do?

I'd take a guess that it is creating a fake, or default, object of this class, but where does it get its parameters? Where is it defined? What does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned in your question, it creates a mock (fake) instance of your object.

The power of this is that it allows you to create powerful tests that can focus on a single object and not be too worried about it's relationships and resource requirements.  For example (using the more modern approach of annotations):

```
@InjectMocks UserService service = new UserService();
@Mock UserRepository repository = new UserRepository();

public void testDelete() {
    List<User> testUsers = generateTestUsers();
    when(repository.findAllUsers()).thenReturn(testUsers);
    service.deleteUsers();

}
```

The above is an example of testing a service level method without having to worry about the database dependency.  This means that the test is repeatable, efficient and focused more on the functionality that you want to test.

See this link for more detailed information:
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a static method that has been [statically imported](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html#staticimport) in your class. You probably have something like

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
```

or

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

in your class. It could also come from another mocking framework than Mockito.

Anyway, this is just a regular static method, which is documented. Read its API doc.